# How to find out the amount of free physical memory under linux (in c)

Tags: linux, memory-management

Assume I want to cache certain calculations, but provoking syncing it out to disk would incur an I/O penalty that would more than defy the whole purpose of caching.

This means, I need to be able find out, how much physical RAM is left (including cached memory, assuming I can push that out and allowing for some slack should buffering increase). I looked into /proc/meminfo and know how to read it out. I am not so sure how to combine the numbers to get what i want though. Code not necessary, once i know what I need I can code it myself.

I will not have root on the box it needs to run at, but it should be reasonably quiet otherwise. No large amount of disk I/O, no other processes claiming a lot of mem in a burst. The OS is a rather recent linux with overcommitting turned on. This will need to work without triggering the OOM killer obviously.

The Numbers don't need to be exact down to the megabyte, I assume that it'll be roughly in the 1 to 7 gib range depending on the box but getting close to about 100 mb would be great.

It'd definitely be preferable if the estimate were to err on the smallish side.

Comment: Be careful with this. If you do it wrong, (especially if you run into another program also trying to do similar memory amount-based caching tricks), you'll end up trashing. See [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/18/10257834.aspx) for some ways it can go wrong. If you do take this approach, pick your amount of memory to use once and only once and just stick to that.

Comment: Thanks, good read. As mentioned, i won't be in that situation. Likely i'll be the only non-service program running on that box, so this will not bite me.

Answer (score 4):

Unices have the standard `sysconf()` function ([OpenGroups man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sysconf.html), [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf)).

Using this function, you can get the total physical memory:

```
unsigned long long ps = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
unsigned long long pn = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
unsigned long long availMem = ps * pn;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think that's not it. I wrote a tiny program to test this:

`unsigned long long pn = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
unsigned long long ps = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
printf("avaiable Pages: %llu of size %llu Bytes\n", pn, ps);`

With the result:

`./memtest; free
avaiable Pages: 7935 of size 4096 Bytes. 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2041140    2009400      31740          0      74136     740620
-/+ buffers/cache:    1194644     846496
Swap:      2103292     428480    1674812`
So swap must be counted for avphys_pages.

Comment: BTW: though this is the preferred sulution, sysconf() returns a **signed** long int (and uses -1 to return an error or "undefined" value). Assigning it to an unsigned int may result in erroneous high values.

Comment: You want `_SC_PHYS_PAGES`, see here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Query-Memory-Parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer of H2CO3, you can read from /proc/meminfo.

Comment: I already do, as mentioned, but i have trouble to figure out which numbers to use.

Answer (score -1):

For  me, statfs worked well.

```
#include <sys/vfs.h>

struct statfs buf;
size_t available_mem;
if ( statfs( "/", &buf ) == -1 ) 
    available_mem = 0;
else 
    available_mem = buf.f_bsize * buf.f_bfree;
```