# How to write a c++ program using linux system call which gives output about free memory, used memory, kernel version?

Tags: c++, linux

On a Linux system, using a C++ program, I need to find a way to print out the following information:

1. Amount of memory in use.
2. Amount of Free memory
3. Linux Kernel Version.

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: you could use `standard c` instead of `c++` ??

Comment: could this be of help ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883606/how-to-find-out-the-amount-of-free-physical-memory-under-linux-in-c

Comment: This is a very confusing and unclear question. What is the memory you are talking about? "amount of free memory" is *very* ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) file system (it is specific to Linux). You might read sequentially `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/version` (these pseudo-files should be read sequentially, and they are quick, not involving any disk IO). You could also use [uname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) for the version of the kernel.

If you want to query about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) for your own [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), use `/proc/self/maps`

If you need information related to [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), use [malloc_info(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html), [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html), [malloc_stats(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html), ...

The comment by [mlwn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2203541/mlwn) also mentions rightly [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)

See also [linuxatemyram](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/). And read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

It is possible to limit the used (or available) memory, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26860944/841108). Use [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) to query the resource limits.

<sup>PS. Your mention of *amount of memory in use* is **very ambiguous**! Notice also that [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are not the same as [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)</sup>